# JavaScript: $(document).ready блокирует вызов функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Почему в этом куске кода функция onclick вызваннная из тела документа не работает?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    function count_rabbits() {
            for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
               // оператор + соединяет строки
               alert("Из шляпы достали "+i+" кролика!")
            }
        }
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="count_rabbits()" value="Считать кролей!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

А если удалить `$(document).ready(function () {}`, то начнет работать.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4o96ghfv/

Comment: Все правильно, вы изолировали ее, она доступна только внутри `document ready`, почитайте про область видимости.

Comment: Возможно потому что у Вас там чистый JS, в jQuery необходимо обращение к объектам $ или jQuery.
Если я ошиваюсь не судите строго)

Comment: @ultimatum, да, ошибаешься

Comment: @Grundly  я только учусь, сорян

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при использовании inline-Обработчиков, вроде

```
onclick="count_rabbits()"
```

используемая **функция должна быть**

1. глобальной
2. объявлена *до* использования в разметке.

В данном случае, функция *count_rabbits* локальная и к ней нет доступа извне.

Для решения, нужно просто вынести ее из `$(document).ready(function () {`